# Not able to access a variable inside array map function

Tags: php, arrays, scope

I want to add a key in the multidimensional array using the `array_map()` function.

```
$keywords = [['keyword'=>'designing'],['keyword'=>'logo designing']];
$user_id = 5;
$keywords = array_map(function($arr){
    return $arr + ['user_id' => $user_id];
}, $keywords);
```

I want the output as

```
$keywords = [['user_id'=>5,'keyword'=>'designing'],['user_id'=>5,'keyword'=>'logo designing']];
```

but it's showing undefined variable `$user_id`.

Comment: why you need this redundant data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$user_id` is [not known in the anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) passed as the first argument to [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

You can easily solve this by using the [`use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-164) that lets the function inherit the `$user_id` variable defined in the parent context.

```
$keywords = [['keyword'=>'designing'],['keyword'=>'logo designing']];
$user_id = 5;

$keywords = array_map(function($arr) use ($user_id) {
    return $arr + ['user_id' => $user_id];
}, $keywords);
```

Comment: it's getting the user_id value as blank but in above it's 5

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple `use` statement:

```
$keywords = array_map(function($arr) use ($user_id) {
    return $arr + ['user_id' => $user_id];
}, $keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify rows by reference and pass in the user_id value as the third parameter of `array_walk()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/set2j))

```
array_walk($keywords, fn(&$v, $k, $u) => $v = ['user_id' => $u] + $v, $user_id);
```

Or with arrow functions, you can pass the user_id value without relying on `use()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GjDn3))

```
var_export(
    array_map(fn($v) => ['user_id' => $user_id] + $v, $keywords)
);
```